# SwiftUI ScrollView Animation Not Working as Expected

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm facing an issue with SwiftUI where the animation doesn't seem to work as expected in a ScrollView. I've created a minimal, reproducible example with a list of messages, and I want to scroll to the bottom of the list with a smooth animation when a new message is added. However, the animation doesn't happen consistently or smoothly. What might be causing this problem, and how can I fix it?

I have a SwiftUI view that contains a ScrollView with a list of messages displayed in a chat-like interface. When a new message is added to the list, I want the view to automatically scroll to the bottom to show the latest message. To achieve this, I'm using the onChange modifier along with the proxy.scrollTo method, wrapped in a withAnimation block. However, the animation doesn't consistently work as expected.

```
import SwiftUI

 struct ContentView: View {
@State private var chats = ["Message 1", "Message 2", "Message 3"]

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        ScrollViewReader { proxy in
            ScrollView {
                ForEach(chats, id: \.self) { message in
                    Text(message)
                        .padding()
                        .id(message)
                        .onChange(of: chats.count) { newCount in
                            if newCount > 0 {
                                withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 1.0)) {
                                    proxy.scrollTo(chats.indices.last, anchor: .bottom)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn’t reproduce your problem on my iPad running iPadOS 16.6.1 (the latest released version as of right now).

That said, I see one real bug in your code and one questionable thing that might also be giving you problems.

The real bug is that you use `.id(message)` to tag each `Text`, where `message` is a `String`. But then you say `proxy.scrollTo(chats.indices.last, ...)`, where `chats.indices.last` is an `Int`. So your scroll target is never going to be found by the proxy.

The questionable thing is that you’re attaching an `onChange` modifier to every `Text`. If there are 100 messages, do you need all 100 of them to run the `onChange` closure? Answer: no. Try attaching the `onChange` modifier to a single view within the `ScrollView`. I’d wrap all the `Text`s in a `VStack` and attach the `onChange` to the `VStack`, like this:

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var chats = (1 ... 15).map { "Message \($0)" }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Add new message") {
                chats.append("Message \(chats.count + 1)")
            }
            ScrollViewReader { proxy in
                ScrollView {
                    VStack {
                        ForEach(chats, id: \.self) { message in
                            Text(message)
                                .padding()
                                .id(message)
                        }
                    }
                    .onChange(of: chats.count) { newCount in
                        if newCount > 0 {
                            withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 1.0)) {
                                proxy.scrollTo(chats.last!, anchor: .bottom)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView())
```